# Cannot attach some processes by ptrace?

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, ptrace

OS: Android 4.3 & 4.4 (root)

Hi all, I try to attach all the processes by calling ptrace(),
my tested app can be attached but some processes can't be, for which I list them below:

I guess the reason may be its special properties, but what's the detail and root cause?
Thank you!

a2mp
ad_calc_wq
aicl_check_wq
apr_driver
bam_dmux_rx
batt_timer
bdi-default
binder
button
cable_detect
cfg80211
cfinteractive
charger_ctrl_ti
crypto
dbs_sync/0
deferwq
detect
devfreq_wq
diag_cntl_wq
ecryptfs-kthrea
ext4-dio-unwrit
f_mtp
f9923000.spi
file-storage
flush-179:0
fsnotify_mark
hdmi_tx_workq
ipc_rtr_q6_ipcr
IPCRTR
irq/102-msm_iom
jbd2/mmcblk0p22
k_gserial
kblockd
kdbs_up/0
keychord
kgsl_devfreq_wq
khelper
khubd
kpsmoused
krfcommd
ksoftirqd/0
kswapd0
kthreadd
kworker/0:0
l2cap
MC_Thread
mcu_poll_reuqes
mdss_dsi_event
mhl_sii8240_855
migration/0
mmc_stats
mmcqd/0
modem_notifier
monitor_tsense_
mpm
netns
ngd_msm_ctrl_ng
nmea
ONEWIRE_WQ
perflock_setrat
pm_workerq_venu
qmi
qpnp-gpled
rpm-smd
rq_stats
rt5506_gpio_off
RX_Thread
sb-1
sii8240_sii8558
smd_channel_clo
smsm_cb_wq
suspend_sys_syn
SYN_ATT_reuqest
sync_supers
system
tps61310_wq
TX_Thread
uether
usb_bam_wq
watchdog/0
...

Comment: I would be interested in seeing the code which calls ptrace.

Answer (score 1):

Those are kernel threads, not user-space processes.

Comment: No.  That would mean you were ptracing the kernel itself.